# Using slugs with Django (Form + Model)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, slug

I have the following error:

[Error in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nBwG.jpg)

[Django admin DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrrcy.jpg)

[Shell object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcB4T.jpg)

The logic that I use in Django is based on a model and the ModelForm class.
Here is the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.urls import reverse


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Recipe(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=250)
    preparation = models.TextField(null=False)
    score = models.IntegerField(null=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    last_update = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    presentation_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.slug}, {self.title}, {self.description}, {self.preparation}, {self.score}, {self.last_update}, {self.presentation_image}, {self.ingredients}'
```

Here is the RecipeForm:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

from .models import Recipe
from .models import Ingredient


class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        exclude = ['slug', 'last_update']
        widgets = {
            'preparation': forms.Textarea()
        }
        labels = {
            'title': 'Title',
            'description': 'Description',
            'preparation': 'Preparation',
            'score': 'Score',
            'presentation_image': 'Presentation Image',
            'ingredients': 'Ingredients'
        }
```

I understand that the problem is based on the fact that no slug is generated (since it is None in the shell). Since my path for a single recipe is based on a slug then Django simply tells me "Hey dude, no slug to work with, sorry... It's on you...".

This problem have occured when I tried to add a new recipe from the Django admin instead of my page ([Here I can add the recipe but the slug will be None. In Django admin I just get the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8G6m.jpg))

What I can't understand is why the slug is not generated?
The user must not enter a slug by it's own. It should be generated based on the title. User must not have a saying in it at the moment.

Can you please explain to me where my logic fails and what's the mistake so I can understand the issue clearly so I can avoid these rookie mistakes in the future?

Comment: Where is the code for generating slug?

Comment: There are only 2 ways. 1) user inputs 2)you generate by other user inputs.

Comment: @Pycm I thought that it will be generated automatically by Django based on the title. That's the mistake? It must be implemented by me in a specific function?

Comment: Yes. Only automatic primary key and id is generated automatically.

Comment: There's another problem. See here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78135424/13861187

Comment: Blank, null = true and unique = true is bad idea.

Comment: Got it now. Thank you for your help. Now I understand the mistake. :)

Comment: @Pycm After what you told me I think of the following modification: implement a save method that will use slugify and provide the so called slug for my recipe and leave the slug only to unique since I don't want slug repeated? Or should the slug be a combination of the title and a random number or something like this?

Comment: Yes. Custom save method is the best. Unique is enough. Yes. Combine with random string if you want uniqueness.

Comment: @Pycm I will try to look into some good practices on google or youtube for the fields so I make sure that I will know how to structure them in the right way. Thank you for your help :)